# Where do I download java packages?

Tags: java, download, installation, package

I'm trying to import this package

```
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.*;
```

So that I can use Eclipse's browser widget, but I can't find out where to download the package, and I don't know how to install it either.

Comment: Just getting the classes do not mean they have all they need.  You most likely need to create a Eclipse SWT application.

Answer (score 2):

See [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/swt/how-to-import-swt-library-into-eclipse-workspace/) on how to import the `SWT` library in your workspace.

Generally, you'll find packages as `.jar` files on the developer's website. The [Eclipse tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jar) has a section on how to add external jars to your buildpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can find download links and installation instructions at http://www.eclipse.org/swt/